# Appending wrapped elements doesn't include wrapper

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying understand why the `.wrap()` function in my basic table of contents function isn't working. The function filters headers from a textarea and places them in an iframe, and the basic part works. But whereas my desired output is this:

```
<ul>
<li class="toc_h2">This is an h2</li>
<li class="toc_h3">This is an h3</li>
<li class="toc_h1">This is an h1</li>
</ul>
```

What I am actually getting is this:

```
<ul>
<h2>This is an h2</h2>
<h3>This is an h3</h3>
<h1>This is an h1</h1>
</ul>
```

How can I fix this/what am I misunderstanding? The code is here and at http://jsfiddle.net/supertrue/JgWxJ/

```
headers.each(function(i) {
   $(this).wrap('<li class="toc_' + this.nodeName.toLowerCase() + '"></li>').appendTo(toc);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change this:

```
 $(this).wrap('<li class="toc_' + this.nodeName.toLowerCase() + '"></li>').appendTo(toc);
```

to this:

```
 $('<li class="toc_' + this.nodeName.toLowerCase() + '"></li>').html(this).appendTo(toc);
```

Here's your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JgWxJ/7/

---

Alternatively, you could just add `.parent()` before appending:

```
$(this).wrap('<li class="toc_' + this.nodeName.toLowerCase() + '"></li>').parent().appendTo(toc);
```

...and here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JgWxJ/10/

Comment: Thanks. I wanted to remove the h1/h2/h3 tags, so I changed `html(this)` to `html(this.innerHTML)`. I still don't really understand why my original wouldn't work, though; I'd love to know how to do this while staying in jQuery.

Comment: @supertrue - Either way you are staying in jQuery. You could have used your first version, if you add `.parent()` to it. See my updated answer.